Help with my proof of the triangle inequality
I am trying to prove the triangle inequality for $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.
I know there are proofs out there, but I would like help with my own proof.
I have: For $ x,y \in \mathbb{R}^{n} $
$|x+y|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i}^2 + 2\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i}{y_i} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}{y_i}^2$
and
$(|x|+|y|)^2  = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i}^2 + 2(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i}^2)^\frac{1}{2}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{y_i}^2)^\frac{1}{2} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}{y_i}^2$
If I subtract the two equations, I end up with:
$(|x|+|y|)^2 - |x+y|^2 = 2(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i}^2)^\frac{1}{2}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{y_i}^2)^\frac{1}{2} - 2\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i}{y_i}$
This is where I'm stuck. I don't know how to reason past this, and the proofs I've seen use the cauchy-schwarz inequality but I don't seem to understand those proofs.
Any help would be much appreciated.

You need Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to finish.

" I've seen use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality but I don't seem to understand those proofs." What precisely don't you understand? The statement of CS itself? (if so, what is unclear in it?), Its proof? (which one?) How it is used here?

I don't know what to do with the fact that the $x^2$ and $y^2$ bits have the square root applied to them. I also didn't consider using the cauchy schwarz inequality till I saw the solution. I didn't know how I would come up with using it myself.

You don't have to come up with it yourself because Cauchy and Schwarz came up with it for you. They came up with it by a process of thinking about the problem for some time, trying out various things, until by a combination of great familiarity and serendipity they were able to prove the thing needed (i.e., how things generally get proved for the first time). As for how you would know to use it. What you want to show in your final equation is that the LH side is $\ge 0$, which requires the RH side is $\ge 0$. But setting the RH side to be $\ge 0$ and dividing by $2$ is exactly Cauchy-Schwarz.
